# What are the possible data we can get it from FORM submit in website

Tags: java, asp.net, ruby-on-rails, forms

What are the possible data we can get it from Linux system or windows OS through the website. Here the case is

1)I login into example.com as a user or creating the account in example.com .. it's all just form submit and they can get the OS name, browser details, IP address, Computer resolution.

Can we get the serial number of the computer or 
Can we get the MAC ID of the computer or
what are the possible data that any website can collect about the user .. it may be in ANY PROGRAMMING Language like JSP, Java servlet or Ruby on Rail or ASP .NET . Please let me know

Comment: You'll want to look up about the [`user agent`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) HTTP header. It will give you a string containing the OS & browser software: `Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU OS 3_2_1 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/531.21.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/7B405`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can get the required data in rails except MAC Address.

By using `request` you will get the data as follows:

```
request.ip
```

Use socket program to get the details like

```
require 'socket'
socket.gethostName
```

and so on

Just go through this [Ruby Socket Programming](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/socket/rdoc/Socket.html) once..,

Answer (score 2):

You can't get the MAC address. This does not pass outside the local area network.

You do get the IP address, from that you can look up the probable location of the user. You also get a query string.

http://mybrowserinfo.com/detail.asp?bhcp=1

Try using this site, to see the sorts of things you can learn or infer. Of course, most items can be spoofed. How to retrieve the information is dependent on the language used, and the source - location is normally gathered via a maxminds lookup to a downloaded copy of their GEO database for example.